# Button operation back in navigation

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation

I have such navigation in a small application:

```js
function MainStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name='Learning' component={Learning}
          options={({ route }) => ({
            title: route.params.screen
          })} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

In the **Learning screen**, I write to `AsyncStorage`

When I return to the **Home screen** I would like to display this content (from `AsyncStorage`)

How do you call a function in **Home** that receives data from `AsyncStorage` as soon as it returns from the **Learning screen** to the **Home screen**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it in the documentation:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/

You can use `useIsFocused`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile() {
  // This hook returns `true` if the screen is focused, `false` otherwise
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  return <Text>{isFocused ? 'focused' : 'unfocused'}</Text>;
}
```

If you want it to refresh screen after goBack, do something like this at `Home`:

```
function Home(props) {
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isFocused) {
            // Do something
        }
    });

// Rest of code
```